# Cannot display a number of input fields given a value

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to display  fields based on the value of a props so let's say my props value = 2 then I want to display 2 inputs but I can't manage to get it work.
This is what I tried

```
 const [numberOfFields, setNumberOfFields] = useState(0);
 const [loadFields, setloadFields] = useState([]);

 const addField = () => {
        return loadFields.map((tier) => {
            <div>
                <p style={{color:'black'}}>Tier {tier + 1}</p>
                <InputNumber />
            </div>
        })
    }
    const onPropsValueLoaded = (value) => {
        let tmp = value
        setNumberOfFields(tmp);
        if (numberOfFields > 0) {
            const generateArrays = Array.from(value).keys()
            setloadFields(generateArrays);
        } else {
            setloadFields([]);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        onPropsValueLoaded(props.numberOfTiers);
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            <Button type="primary" onClick={showModal}>
                Buy tickets
            </Button>
            <Modal
                title="Buy ticket"
                visible={visible}
                onOk={handleOk}
                confirmLoading={confirmLoading}
                onCancel={handleCancel}
            >
                <p style={{ color: 'black' }}>{props.numberOfTiers}</p>
                {loadFields.length ? (
                    <div>{addField()}</div>
                ) : null}
                <p style={{ color: 'black' }}>Total price: </p>
            </Modal>
        </>
    );
```

so here props.NumberOfTiers = 2 so I want 2 input fields to be displayed but right now none are displayed even though loadFields.length is not null
I am displaying this inside a modal (even though I don't think it changes anything).

I am doing this when I load the page that's why I am using the useEffect(), because if I use a field and update this onChange it works nicely.

EDIT:
I changed the onPropsValueLoaded() function

```
const generateArrays = Array.from({length : tmp}, (v,k) => k)
```

instead of

```
const generateArrays = Array.from(value).keys()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things you should fix in here,

**First,** you need to return `div` in `addField` function to render the inputs.

**Second,** you should move your function `onPropsValueLoaded` inside `useEffect` or use [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html) to prevent effect change on each render.

**Third,** your method of creating array using [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) is not correct syntax which should be `Array.from(Array(number).keys())`.

So the working code should be , I also made a sample [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-phoebe-t13gdp?file=/src/App.js)

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [numberOfFields, setNumberOfFields] = useState(0);
  const [loadFields, setloadFields] = useState([]);

  const addField = () => {
    return loadFields.map((tier) => {
      return (
        <div key={tier}>
          <p style={{ color: "black" }}>Tier {tier + 1}</p>
          <input type="text" />
        </div>
      );
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let tmp = 2; // tier number
    setNumberOfFields(tmp);
    if (numberOfFields > 0) {

      const generateArrays = Array.from(Array(tmp).keys());
      setloadFields(generateArrays);
    } else {
      setloadFields([]);
    }
  }, [numberOfFields]);



  return (
    <>
      <button type="button">Buy tickets</button>

      <p style={{ color: "black" }}>2</p>
      {loadFields.length ? <div>{addField()}</div> : null}
      <p style={{ color: "black" }}>Total price: </p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I've tried changes you told me to do and it does not work. It does actually works on your sample though. I am not sure why? Do you think using a modal to display the inputs make it not work?

Comment: Could be, but I don't think that's the case. Try console logging `generateArrays` in your code and if you still get empty value, then there's something wrong with getting tier number and creating an array. If you get values in `generateArrays` , then you should focus on rendering which could be related to modal in this case.

Comment: Ye my generateArrays is empty that's probably why

Comment: Ok fixed it with this ``` const generateArrays = Array.from({length : tmp}, (v,k) => k)
```

Comment: Cool, glad you found the answer.